# Drawable from URL limited memory in android

Tags: java, android, memory

I want go get image from URL and convert it into drawable. I have this method, that works fine:

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
}
```

Except one thing. When image is too big app crashes.

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(12750): 13142360-byte external allocation too large for this process.
E/dalvikvm(12750): Out of memory: Heap Size=6023KB, Allocated=3177KB, Bitmap Size=2563KB, Limit=20480KB
E/dalvikvm(12750): Trim info: Footprint=6023KB, Allowed Footprint=6023KB, Trimmed=952KB
E/GraphicsJNI(12750): VM won't let us allocate 13142360 bytes
```

Can I somehow increase the memory that I need for the image? Or maybe there is a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is the code that finaly works.
As suggested I reduced the size of image using given function: calculateInSampleSize - thx Androyds.

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(String url, Context context) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
bufferedInputStream.mark(connection.getContentLength());
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);
bufferedInputStream.reset();

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 400, 400);

x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, null, options);

bufferedInputStream.close();
connection.disconnect();

    BitmapDrawable y = new BitmapDrawable(x);

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

the above link returns the re-sized bitmap from url, then you can convert to bitmap drawable.

Download and use the Bitmap fun sample application from that link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale down the image or resize it as this link suggested

[Loading Large Image](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Here are some code snippet for this:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    } else {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }
}
return inSampleSize;
}
```

Just call this part when you set your drawable

```
MyImageview.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), mydrawable, 420, 620));
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a java noob so far. How do I call this: MyImageview.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), mydrawable, 420, 620)); inside my getDrawableFromUrl(String url) function?

Comment: @baron_bartek are you trying to get image from URL?

Comment: Yes. I finally have code that works based on your function. Please see my answear.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save the file temporary on phone and read it and use it as a drawable. But if the phone cannot load the image, then you need to scale down the image from the sender or before opening it.